# Create, Delete, Update Contacts windows phone 8 with .net

Tags: .net, windows-phone, .net-4.5, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to create new contact or update/delete pre-existing contact in window phone 8 SDK? .Net or Native code, I need to allow my app to manage the contacts regardless the contact account (Google, Microsoft ...) similar as the build-in contact app can do,

I appreciate your help.
Thanks
Sam

Comment: Windows Phone 8 does introduce a [Custom contact store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207034(v=vs.105).aspx) but I don't think it gives you all of the capabilities you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the contacts belonging to Gmail or any other service. You can add a contact to the People Hub and that contact will be stored in Contact Store which is associated with the app. Once the app is uninstalled the contact will be removed with it. This prevents People Hub getting spammed with the app contacts.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim mentioned, the Custom contact store is probably the closest thing to what you want.  This wasn't possible in Windows Phone 7 and the [What's new in the SDK for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) doesn't mention any change.

I wouldn't expect this to change - generally for other companies to get full access to contacts from other services (like Facebook, for example), I've heard they're not allowed to expose the data programmatically.  This was the case on webOS at least (again, just what I've heard)...

Comment: Many thanks Jim and gregstoll, the custom contact store is very limited, actually I need to edit pre-existing Google and other services accounts, anyway many thanks of your help. I'm new to WP8 development, I found lots of limitation in the SDK, SD Card is read only can't export to SD, Now the Contact Limitation, ... very basic OS comparing to Android